# Do Crusades or Holy Wars Affect Infamy?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The infamy mechanic has been added as of Patch 2.5.1. It's supposed to work in a similar way to aggressive expansion in EU4, where by conquering provinces will contribute towards your infamy score which is represented by a percentage. If that score reaches 25% your neighbours will start to form coalitions against you.

But does anyone know whether Crusades or Holy wars will contribute to this infamy score?

If say, I'm France and a Crusade is called for Jerusalem and I'm the largest contributor therefore gaining all the provinces in the Kingdom of Jerusalem. Will all my Christian neighbours who also fought alongside me suddenly form a coalition against me because gaining all those provinces blew my infamy score sky high?

Or say I'm Castille and I start a Holy War for the Algarve. Is infamy constrained by Religion Group or will a Holy war against a different religion group increase my infamy also?

I've searched for some documentation on how the infamy mechanic is supposed to work but can't find any real explanation.

Comment: An important question, especially since in my last game I found that the king of West Francia adopted the Lollard faith. Such circumstances, whilst quite rare, can lead to numerous holy wars over the years

Comment: Regarding your *christian neighbors* forming a coalition against you: I haven't played the game since the council update, but as far as I heard a lot of people complain that coalitions seem to ignore both religious affiliation and proximity and that they frequently see coalitions formed by characters of different faiths in completely different regions. Like the Abbasid caliphate joining a coalition against someone in England.

Comment: It looks like Paradox have heard the complaints and will be releasing a patch to fix the issues of coalitions forming from differing religion groups and over vast distances

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears Holy wars do affect infamy as would pressing any claim. However Crusades have no impact on infamy at all.

In my current game as the Emperor of Alba I declared a Holy war against the Sultan of Analusia for the Duchy of Beja in Portugal. Beja consists of 4 provinces and when I succeeded, enforcing my demands my infamy score increased by 33%. This led to to all of my neighbours (of mixed religions) within Hispania forming a coalition against me even though some helped me in my 'Just war'.

**Note:** There is an upcoming patch that will look to address the issue of unlikely coalitions ie. difference of religion and distance (so you should no longer see the Kingdom of Norway form a coalition against you with the Turkish Empire!)

Later in the game A crusade was called for the Kingdom of Anatolia. The Crusade was successful and I was the largest contributor gaining me the 20 provinces in Anatolia, which used to belong to the Byzantian Empire. This had no effect on my infamy what so ever.

Comment: Because you are technically not the one winning a war and gaining land (the land is given via event I think) in Crusade-tier wars, you do not get infamy.

Comment: The reason Crusades grant no infamy seems to be because you personally did not declare the war. The Pope declared the war, you joined up later. But because of how Crusades work the person who declared the war doesn't necessarily get the land. This is worth knowing if you try playing a Muslim Caliph, Jihads can absolutely give the Caliph infamy if his realm expands as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Holy Wars, at least, do. As the Byzantine Emperor, I've lead a few holy wars against the Slavs. This has lead to a massive coalition, including most slavic kings (makes sense), but also Catholic Italy and the Muslim Abbassids.

Answer (score 0):

Any territorial gains from wars contribute to your Threat, no matter what the Casus Belli was or who you conquered from.

Great Holy Wars (which are mechanically similar to Crusades) do generate infamy if you are the one who declares them. In my current game I reformed the Germanic faith, which gave me the ability to declare Great Holy Wars. I declared a Great Holy War for Germany, won, gained a large chunk of land and promptly got over the 50% Threat threshold.

The Threat mechanic doesn't account for who you won your wars against. Your brothers in faith will form a defensive pact against you even if all your recent victories were against heathens.